# Firestore Cloud Functions, which is better Multiple Functions or One Big Function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, listener

My Question is, would it be better to combine Functions that use the same `.document` & `.onUpdate` into one big function or have them seperated into small modules of functions?

For example i have two functions that both listen to onUpdate on Users:

```
export const firstUserFunction = functions.firestore
   .document('users/{userId}')
   .onUpdate((change, context) => { 
   const newValue = <{ role: string }>change.after.data();
   const oldValue = <{ role: string }>change.before.data();
   if ((oldValue.role === '1' && newValue.role === '2')) {
       // do something
   }
})
export const secondUserFunction = functions.firestore
   .document('users/{userId}')
   .onUpdate((change, context) => {
   const newValue = <{ template: string }>change.after.data();
   if (newValue.template === 'x') {
       // do something
   } 
})
```

If we look at the pricing, then it would make sense to make combined functions like this:

```
export const combinedFunction = functions.firestore
   .document('users/{userId}')
   .onUpdate((change, context) => { 
   const newValue = <{ role: string, template: string }>change.after.data();
   const oldValue = <{ role: string }>change.before.data();

   if ((oldValue.role === '1' && newValue.role === '2')) {
       // do something
   }

   if (newValue.template === 'x') {
       // do something
   } 
})
```

instead of small ones, but are there any disadvantages of having bigger ones?

If its better to combine them, what would you consider the limit?

Comment: I have a strong preference to have only trigger for each type/path combination. If multiple effects are needed for a single trigger, I much rather handle that in my own code by calling multiple (normal) functions from my single Cloud Function, since it allows me to control the flow myself rather than rely on Cloud Functions for that. But this is a personal preference, and there is no single best answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will depend on the specific case. For example, if both the functions would always be called, than it would make sense for you to combine them, since they will be run always together and one function would work.

However, in case both functions will not be run always, it would make sense to have them split, since they will run depending on the situation. In your case, for example, if always the functions `firstUserFunction` and `secondUserFunction` will run at the same time, makes sense to combine, so you can save money and processing.

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: Yeah thanks, it helped to reinsure my question, but i can't take it as an answer because this Post has been locked as an Opinion Question, sorry :)

Comment: Hi @AleksanderRilkov sure! No problem, if you liked the answer, please, consider upvoting it then! Thanks for letting me know!